# Create a DataExtension inside "Salesforce Data Extension" folder using SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, dataextensions, soap

I Was trying to create a DE inside the Salesforce Data Extension folder using a SOAP request. The call is performed correctly, but i get this error: `Unable to save data extension into a non-data extension category.  The category provided was of type salesforcedataextension.`

I tried to change the object type in "salesforcedataextension" but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to be able to create a data extension inside that folder?

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware of. We want to do this too, in order that IERs are created inside Salesforce for our externally-triggered and created sends.

At the moment we're stuck between what's possible with Content Builder and the updated UI, the limited REST API, the SOAP API which can't address new bits like Content Builder emails, and the documentation which is ********.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is still a problem.

**A work-around:** I created a data extension in the 'Data Extensions' folder using the SOAP API, then, in the user interface, moved the data extension into a child folder under the 'Salesforce Data Extensions' folder.